What happened to DevTools and why are they painfully slow now?
I've recently updated Chrome DevTools, now debugging is painfully slow. What happened?
This seems to have worked for me, hope it helps!

Open DevTools settings
Click "Experiments" tab
Scroll to the bottom of the list
Uncheck "Enable speculative loads panel..."
Uncheck "Enable the legacy tracing model..."
Restart browser




If you have DevTools open in other tabs/windows, ensure they get reloaded. The issue may persist if all panes haven't been refreshed.
